# Ping out from a specific NIC

Tags: networking, nic

I have a server with dual NICs, both of which have IP addresses in the same subnet.
How would I send a ping out over a particular (chosen) NIC ?

Thanks .. KJ

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you're using Windows, the closest equivalent is "ping -S [source address]".

Answer (score 5):

You should have specified which operating system you are using.

Under Linux, you just use `ping -I $interface`, as the manpage can easily tell you.